# Keyboard shortcut for viewing the next parameter hint?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a keyboard shortcut that does the equivalent of pressing either of the buttons circled in red in this image?:[image: screenshot]?

I've tried looking through the shortcut list but I'm not exactly sure what the name of the command would be.

Comment: The Up and Down keys?

Comment: @Casey The up and down keys navigate through the autocomplete dropdown instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you.

The "Up" and "Down" keys are shortcut keys when using this function, but because other prompt boxes sometimes pop up when using this function, the "Up" and "Down" keys are intercepted by other prompt boxes, like this:

[image]

However, you can enter any number and then delete it, which will make the other prompt box disappear:

[image]

In this way, the "Up" and "Down" keys work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can click `Ctrl + Shift + Space` to focus this parameters list. And after, you can use arrows (up, down)